# Adicionando DLL Referenciada em um Executável C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

desenvolvi uma aplicação console em C# que faz uso de uma dll referenciada. 
Após fazer o batch build e gerar o executável da aplicação, tentei rodá-la em um computador que não possuía esta dll, naturalmente ocorreu um erro. Logo em seguida passei a dll para o computador e deixei na mesma pasta do .exe e o mesmo ocorreu.

Sei que necessito de alguma forma linkar essa dll na hora do build, ou algo do gênero, porém não sei como.
Gostaria de saber como gerar esse executável de forma que ele funcione em outro computador?

Comment: Tente via `Project > Add reference...` e depois certifique-se que a DLL está na pasta `bin\debug` (ou `release`, dependendo do contexto usado) da sua aplicação

Answer (score 3):

Antes de dar o `batch` da aplicação, vá na sua referência e faça o seguinte:

Botão direito em cima dela e vá em propriedades, depois disso altere o `Copy Local` para `TRUE`

Faça seu `batch` e verá que agora a `dll` está duplicada em sua aplicação, envie dessa maneira para o outro computador e pronto.